# Java Swing JComboBox action listener

Tags: java, sockets, enums

Edit:
Problem was calling methods like `jcc.setSelectedIndex(-1)` will trigger any listeners attached to the combo box. I was under the impression only user events would cause them.

Answer (score 1):

You created textFiled with a Listener which is reacted in your case :

```
 fontpkr.addActionListener(ev -> {
        //make sure only enabled when text box is selected
        DTextModel dtm = (DTextModel)Ctrl.getSelectedModel();
        dtm.setFontIdxAndNotify(fontpkr.getSelectedIndex());
    });
```

if we just go by methods inside: 
`setFontIdxAndNotify(..)`   calling -> `Ctrl.server.bcastFontIdxChange(i)`  and at the end :

```
public void bcastFontIdxChange(int newIdx) {
    try {
        os.writeObject(Pkt.FONT_CHANGE);
        os.writeInt(newIdx);
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

There is your wrong enum **Pkt.FONT_CHANGE**